# count up Progressbar without any threads

Tags: java, android

how can i count up Progressbar and freeze any thing else simply count up to 10 sec (update every sec).

```
ProgressBar PB;
index=0;
while(index<10)

   {
     /*************  wait(one sec)/*********/
     PB.setProgress(index);
     index++;
   }
```

can any body tell me what this code do

```
while(index<10)
{

    android.os.SystemClock.sleep(1000);//sleep please here one sec
    PB.setprogressbar(index);         //no i sleep 10 sec and then  index=10!!!!
        index++;
}
```

i will no't use threads,

Comment: You are **not** supposed to freeze the UI thread, it will throw an ANR.

Comment: Multithreading are there for reasons like this, to perform background jobs. Why the hesitation to use another thread?

Comment: You _will_ have to thread no matter what. Freezing the UI is *not* an option and a _very_ bad design idea.

Comment: exactly, i know that very well, but i need to demonstrate, what the different between multitreading using und not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that because the loop is very fast and it always executes the `sleep(1000)`.